# How to retrieve data from database and Display in JSP?

Tags: jsp

### I am trying to Retrieve data then display it in table but I get empty table even the dao is worked properly. I don't know where is the problem.Here is everything in my code. Please help me because I have to submit these code tomorrow to my doctor

ManagerSearch.jsp:

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>All Data Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-image: url(derma1.jpg); height: 900px; width: 1905px;
             font-size: 1em;  color: #1572c1; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
             text-align: center; ">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Birth Date</th>
                    <th>Place Of Birth</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Nationality</th>
                    <th>Current Address</th>
                    <th>City Address</th>
                    <th>Marital Status</th>
                    <th>Offspring</th>
                    <th>Age Of Youngest Offspring</th>
                    <th>Work Nature</th>
                    <th>Phone Number</th>
                    <th>E-Mail</th>
                </tr>
                 <c:forEach items="${AllDataSearch}" var="p">
                    <tr>

                        <td>${p.iD}</td>
                        <td>${p.patientName}</td>
                        <td>${p.birthDate}</td>
                        <td>${p.placeOfBirth}</td>
                        <td>${p.gender}</td>
                        <td>${p.nationality}</td>
                        <td>${p.currentAddress}</td>
                        <td>${p.citytAdress}</td>
                        <td>${p.maritalStatus}</td>
                        <td>${p.offspring}</td>
                        <td>${p.ageOfYoungestOffspring}</td>
                        <td>${p.workNature}</td>
                        <td>${p.phoneNumber}</td>
                        <td>${p.eMail}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dermatology Clinic</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='deleteForm.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="container">
      <div class="header">
  <img src="logo1.png" alt="logo" />
</div>
             </div>
<div id="container1">
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<a href="AddNew.html">
   <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Add a New Patient</button>
    </div>
  </a>
<a href="Delete.html">
<div class="dropdown">
         <button class="dropbtn">Delete a Patient</button>
        </div>
     </a>

<a href="Update.html">
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Update a Patient</button>
        </div>
                  </a>

<a href="Search.html">
  <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Search For a Patient</button>
        </div>
  </a>
        </div>  
        <div style="background-image: url(derma.jpg); height:714px; width: 1905px;">
            <form action="JSP/ManagerSearch.jsp">
                <p></p>
                <label>
                    ID
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter ID" name="ID">
                </label>
                <p></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
</div>

      </body>

</html>
```

DAO:

```
package DAO;

import Connection.MysqlConnection;
import Tables.PersonalData;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PersonalDataDao {

    public int InsertPersonalData(PersonalData personaldata) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        int affected = 0;
        try {


            PreparedStatement ps = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement("insert into personal_data values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, personaldata.getiD());
            ps.setString(2, personaldata.getPatientName());
            ps.setString(3, personaldata.getBirthDate());
            ps.setString(4, personaldata.getPlaceOfBirth());
            ps.setString(5, personaldata.getGender());
            ps.setString(6, personaldata.getNationality());
            ps.setString(7, personaldata.getCurrentAddress());
            ps.setString(8, personaldata.getCityAddress());
            ps.setString(9, personaldata.getMaritalStatus());
            ps.setString(10, personaldata.getOffspring());
            ps.setString(11, personaldata.getAgeOfYoungestOffspring());
            ps.setString(12, personaldata.getWorkNature());
            ps.setString(13, personaldata.getPhoneNumber());
            ps.setString(14, personaldata.geteMail());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonalDataDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
            throw ex;
        }

        return affected;

    }



    public void delete(String id) {
        try {
            String sql = "DELETE FROM personal_data WHERE iD = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonalDataDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static List<PersonalData> getById(String id) {
        List<PersonalData> ls = new LinkedList<PersonalData>();
        String sql = "select * from personal_data where id = " + id;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement(sql).executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                PersonalData n = new PersonalData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14));
                ls.add(n);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonalDataDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return ls;
    }

    public int edit(String iD, String patientName, String birthDate, String placeOfBirth, String gender, String nationality, String currentAddress, String cityAddress, String maritalStatus, String offspring, String ageOfYoungestOffspring, String workNature, String phoneNumber, String eMail) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        int affected = 0;

        try {
            String sql = "update personal_data SET Patient_Name = ?, Birth_Date = ?, Place_Of_Birth = ?, Gender = ?, Nationality = ?, Current_Address = ?, City_Address = ?, Marital_Status = ?, Offspring = ?, Age_Of_Youngest_Offspring = ?, Work_Nature = ?, Phone_Number = ?, E_mail = ?" + " where ID = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, patientName);
            ps.setString(2, birthDate);
            ps.setString(3, placeOfBirth);
            ps.setString(4, gender);
            ps.setString(5, nationality);
            ps.setString(6, currentAddress);
            ps.setString(7, cityAddress);
            ps.setString(8, maritalStatus);
            ps.setString(9, offspring);
            ps.setString(10, ageOfYoungestOffspring);
            ps.setString(11, workNature);
            ps.setString(12, phoneNumber);
            ps.setString(13, eMail);
            ps.setString(14, iD);

            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonalDataDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       return affected;

    }

    public static List<PersonalData> getAll() {

        List<PersonalData> ls = new LinkedList<>();

        try {
            ResultSet rs = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement("select * from personal_data").executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                PersonalData n = new PersonalData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9), rs.getString(10), rs.getString(11), rs.getString(12), rs.getString(13), rs.getString(14));
                ls.add(n);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PersonalDataDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        return ls;
    }
}
```

Search.java:

```
package servlet;

import DAO.PersonalDataDao;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Search extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String id = request.getParameter("ID");
        request.setAttribute("getById", DAO.PersonalDataDao.getById(id));
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("AllData.jsp");
        try {
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Update.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Assuming your Servlet is actually invoked and the data is loaded then 2 issues: [1] You have not declared the taglib in your JSP. You need to add this to the top of the file: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` [2] You set the retrieved data in the request as an attribute using key 'getById' but try to iterate a collection with the key 'AllDataSearch'. These need to match.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
I don't understand the aim of  the second issue

Comment: I'm sorry to ask these question but I can't understand the servlet very well